# Request handlers for one URL can't be in different Controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my spring mvc (Spring 3.0.2) application I have two different controller methods for
handling the same url pattern but with different methods (GET and SET).
If I have both of them in single controller class it works fine:

```
@Controller
class MainController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/somepage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMethod() {
        return "redirect:/get";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/somepage", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postMethod() {
        return "redirect:/post";
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work when these methods are defined in two different controller classes.
In this case only one method works while another gives me 405 error 
(request method is not supported)
So the question is why, and how can I make it work as expected?

P.S.: Not working code:

```
@Controller
class GetController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/somepage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMethod() {
        return "redirect:/get";
    }
}
@Controller
class PostController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/somepage", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postMethod() {
        return "redirect:/post";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend showing the code that doesn't work and telling us what does work.

Comment: Are they both in the context:component-scan base-package?

Comment: Do both classes exist in the same file?  If not, are they in the same package?

Comment: classes are in different files but in the same package, the package is perfectly scanned by context:component-scan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT :**

It seams it is OK with **3.1.0.M2**, where mappings are done by everything from `@RequestMapping` annotation.

So the best option for you is to change to newest Spring version.

---

**On Spring 3.0.5** this error occurs while beans instantiation:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler 'postController' to URL path [/somepage]: There is already handler of type [class test.GetController] mapped.`

As far as I can see from logs and code, `@Controller` beans are mapped to urls only, while instantiation is done, and method dispatching is done later.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug to me. Try ugprading to 3.0.5 or the latest 3.1 milestone. If the problem persists, create an issue in spring's JIRA.